# How can I make my layout with no tables?

Tags: html, css

I used tables for my layout but I must use DIVs instead because I have forms in my tables. It was a mistake rendering the code with tables because it has forms and the form functionality is experiencing unwanted sideeffects from using tables so I must use DIVs instead for the layout. Can you help me how I achieve my layout with no tables?

[image]

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/k5tfwo35/1/) with my code. The html is

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- v2 -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:15px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
         data-ad-slot="9119838994"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>

    <div id="border1"></div>

<div id="searchbox">

<form id="search_form" action="/account/do_login" method="post">


        <div class="div-table">

            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col">LOG IN</div>
                <div class="div-table-col"><input name="email" size="35" title="email" type="text"
                        ></div>
                <div class="div-table-col"><input name="password" size="35" title="password" type="password"
                        ></div>
                <div class="div-table-col"> <input value="Login" type="submit"></div>   <div class="div-table-col"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col logintext">YOUR E-MAIL</div>
                <div class="div-table-col logintext">PASSWORD</div>
            </div>
    </form>

    <form autocomplete="off" id="create_user" action="/create/" method="post">

        <div class="div-table">

            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col">CREATE ACCOUNT</div>
                <div class="div-table-col"><input name="email" size="35" title="email" type="text"
                        ></div>
                <div class="div-table-col"><input name="password" size="35" title="password" type="password"
                        ></div>
                <div class="div-table-col">  <input value="Create Account" type="submit"></div>
                <div class="div-table-col"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col logintext">YOUR E-MAIL</div>
                <div class="div-table-col logintext">PASSWORD</div>
            </div>

            <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col">OR LOG IN WITH</div>
                <div class="div-table-col"><a href="/auth/google"><img id="googlelink" alt="Login with google" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div> <div class="div-table-col"><a href="/auth/linkedin"> <img id="linkedinlink" alt="Login with linkedin" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div>
                <div class="div-table-col"><a href="/auth/yahoo"><img id="yahoolink" alt="Login with yahoo" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"> </a></div>  <div class="div-table-col"><a href="/auth/facebook"> <img id="facebooklink" alt="Login with facebook" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div>

            </div>

        </div>

</form>


</div>
    <div id="recover"><a href="/passwordreset/"><div class="reminderlink">CLICK HERE TO RECOVER YOUR ACCOUNT</div></A></div>



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

After a while I tried it with bootstrap which didn't work at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-IN" class="js">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description"
          content="Find free ads about all different kind of items for sale in {% if regionname and regionname != 'None' %}{{regionname}}{% else %}{% if cityname and cityname != 'None' %}{{cityname}}{% else %}{% if country and country != 'None' %}{{country}}{% endif %}{% endif %}{% endif %}">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noarchive">
    {% if cursor %}
    <link rel="next" href="/delhi/?o=2">
    {% endif %}
    <link rel="canonical" href="/q">

    <title>Login / Create</title>
    <!-- CSS INCLUDES: -->

    <link href="/static/css/koolindex_in.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HEADEXTRAS: -->

    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon_in.ico?07217" type="image/x-icon">
    <!--
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon_in.ico?07217" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon_in.png?07217" type="image/png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/favicon_ios_in.png?07217" type="image/png">
        <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon_us.ico?51340" type="image/x-icon">
            <link href="https://plus.google.com/123122342342345" rel="publisher">-->

    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/common.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/arrays_v2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/searchbox.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
{% include "kooltopbar.html" %}


<div id="wrapper">
 {% if request.host == "www.koolbusiness.com"  %}
<a href="/">
    <h1 id="logo" class="sprite_index_in_in_en_logo spritetext">koolbusiness.com - The right choice for buying &amp;
        selling in india</h1></a>
{% endif %}


    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- v2 -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:15px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-7211665888260307"
         data-ad-slot="9119838994"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>

    <div id="border1"></div>

<div id="searchbox">
    <div class="container">
<form id="search_form" action="/account/do_login" method="post">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">LOG IN WITH</div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><a href="/auth/google"><img id="googlelink" alt="Login with google" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"> <a href="/auth/linkedin"> <img id="linkedinlink" alt="Login with linkedin" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><a href="/auth/yahoo"><img id="yahoolink" alt="Login with yahoo" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"> </a></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><a href="/auth/facebook"> <img id="facebooklink" alt="Login with facebook" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">LOG IN</div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><input name="email" size="35" title="email" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><input name="password" size="35" title="password" type="password"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input value="Login" type="submit"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 logintext">YOUR E-MAIL</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 logintext">PASSWORD</div>
    </div>

    </form>

    <form autocomplete="off" id="create_user" action="/create/" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">CREATE ACCOUNT</div>
            <div class="col-md-1"><input name="email" size="35" title="email" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"><input name="password" size="35" title="password" type="password"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><input value="Create Account" type="submit"></div>
        </div>


</form>

</div>
</div>
    <div id="recover"><a href="/passwordreset/"><div class="reminderlink">CLICK HERE TO RECOVER YOUR ACCOUNT</div></A></div>



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

### Edit

The way I finally did it was with twitter bootstrap and I'm happy with it. But rearranging everything into DIVs didn't solve the problem of autocomplete with the form so I had to resort to a dirty trick to clear the form for the create field. Strange thing was that I had to restart everything to make twitter bootstrap work.

[image]

```
<div id="mybox">
    <div class="container">
<form id="search_form" action="/account/do_login" method="post">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">LOG IN WITH</div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="/auth/google"><img id="googlelink" alt="Login with google" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> <a href="/auth/linkedin"> <img id="linkedinlink" alt="Login with linkedin" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="/auth/yahoo"><img id="yahoolink" alt="Login with yahoo" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"> </a></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><a href="/auth/facebook"> <img id="facebooklink" alt="Login with facebook" src="/_/img/transparent.gif"></a></div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">LOG IN</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input name="email" size="35" title="email" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input name="password" size="35" title="password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input value="Login" type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 logintext">YOUR E-MAIL</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 logintext">PASSWORD</div>
    </div>

    </form>

    <form autocomplete="off" id="create_user" action="/create/" method="post">
        <input style="display:none">
        <input type="password" style="display:none">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">CREATE ACCOUNT</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input name="email" id="email" size="35" autocomplete="off" title="email" type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input name="password" id="password" size="35" autocomplete="off" title="password" type="password" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input value="Create Account" type="submit">
            </div>
        </div>


</form>
</table>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="recover"><a href="/passwordreset/"><div class="reminderlink">CLICK HERE TO RECOVER YOUR ACCOUNT</div></A></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may be discovering, tables should not be used for layout. As a matter of fact, they should only be used for displaying data.

As far as building a layout with divs, here's what you need to know to get started.

Use width, max-width, and min-width to your advantage to create intuitive and responsive layouts.

Use percent, em, and vh in place of pixels where you can.

Consider learning and using floats, and clear: both to help with responsive layout.

Also, consider using the [twitter bootstrap CSS framework](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). Specifically the grid functionality. You can learn it and use it in minutes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using twitter bootstrap with the grid functionality. It was useless. Didn't work at all.

Comment: It's used by millions and can accomplish most layout jobs, including this one. Be sure to use grids within grids as needed, define your widths in ways that work with the grids, and remove any css rules that may override or conflict with bootstrap styling.

Comment: When I try it, it does nothing. After several hours of work trying different methods, I was better off keeping my html as a table because nothing else is possible. When I add the twitter bootstrap CSS `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">` I still can't make any tables at all even if I use grids and containers. I was better off using a table and not reading these answers.

Comment: nothing wrong with using tables for parts of your layout (if you are smart enough to use them wisely) and bootstrap is ugly, bloated, and hinders learning

Comment: @SteveYancharasJr. All CSS is ugly, bloated and stops everybody from learning. I've tried achieving a basic layout with DIVs now for several hours and I've gotten nowhere better than my table. My only problem was that I had two forms in my table. So I'm going to try it with two tables for the two forms and forget about twitter.

Comment: well if you do it that way i would make two tables and wrap them in divs so that it's still responsive

Comment: I suggested bootstrap because it's helpful for beginners. You don't need it, but I strongly recommend avoiding tables for building your layouts. Browsers, Search Engines, and more expect tables to be used to display data. As browsers and HTML changes over time, they may make changes that break your table layout. Finally, it's just not the way it's done in the industry, so you'll have trouble finding work or starting open source projects. Login forms are common, so look at some examples with your inspect element. Here's some examples. http://www.freshdesignweb.com/css-login-form-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

This layout is ridiculously simple, and you're making it far more complex than it needs to be.  I stripped out all the google ad stuff, which you can add back, but there is way more markup here than you need and way more junk.

Here's a quick fiddle I threw together in about 10 minutes that gives you the basic layout.  I'm sure you can tweak it to the exact dimensions you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/fop9vLjh/1/

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: sans-serif; }
    #wrapper { width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; }
    div { margin-top: 15px; }
    #login-box { background-color: #ffc801; padding: 10px; }
    span { float: left; width: 10em; }
    #recover { float: right; }
    a { text-decoration: none; }
    input[type='text'],input[type='password'] { width: 18em; }
    .form-field { width: 15em; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-top: 0; }
    label { display: block; font-size: small; }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="login-box">
        <div id="login">
            <span>LOGIN</span>
            <form action="/account/do_login" method="post">
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="email" type="text"/>
                    <label for="email">YOUR EMAIL</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="password" type="password"/>
                    <label for="password">PASSWORD</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="Login">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="create">
            <span>CREATE ACCOUNT</span>
            <form autocomplete="off" id="create_user" action="/create/" method="post">
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="email" type="text"/>
                    <label for="email">YOUR EMAIL</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="password" type="password"/>
                    <label for="password">DESIRED PASSWORD</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="Create">Create Account</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="alt-login">
            <span>OR LOG IN WITH</span>
            <input name="google" type="image" src="#"/>
            <input name="linkedin" type="image" src="#"/>
            <input name="yahoo" type="image" src="#"/>
            <input name="facebook" type="image" src="#"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="recover">
        <a href="">CLICK HERE TO RECOVER YOUR ACCOUNT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me but its html\css basics. Where exactly your problem is? I only see the problem with top yellow bar which can be fixed by something like this:

```
html {
    position:absolute;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

But still it looks ugly enough (:

Comment: It's not basic. I bet the work takes more time than anything basic. I didn't know where to begin and it was not obvious how to get this far as the updated question. It would have been much easier to keep the code in table and allow 2 forms in a table instead. Now I updated my code and there are several problems. It won't respond to different number of columns for different rows.